# Adding two COUNT results

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've got a problem with adding two select results. My code is:

```
SELECT a AS total_rows, b
FROM (
   SELECT COUNT (*) as a, E.b as b
   FROM         table1 C
   JOIN         table2 D
   ON           D.MY_ID = C.MY_ID
   JOIN         table3 E
   ON           E.NEW_ID = C.NEW_ID
   WHERE        E.b BETWEEN 1 AND 4
   GROUP BY     E.b
   ORDER BY     E.b
   ) 
UNION ALL (
       SELECT COUNT(*)as a, E.b as b
       FROM          table2 D
       JOIN          table4 S
       ON            S.PERSON_ID IN (D.f_ID, D.g_ID)
       JOIN          table3 E
       ON            E.LOCATION_ID IN (Q.LOC_FROM_ID, Q.LOC_TO_ID)
       WHERE         L.AISLE BETWEEN 1 AND 8
       GROUP BY      E.b
       ORDER BY      E.b)
```

Each Select works perfect when im using them separately. It also works when im trying to do it without selecting E.b.

My goal to achive is to display the results of both selects added to each other but it must be grouped by E.b column and E.b column must be viseable in the result.

Comment: Didn't understand your problem, what isn't working?

Comment: isn't easier for you to create #TempTable and insert results in it from both select and then just get what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your **UNION ALL** query as a **sub-query** and get the **SUM** of the count.

```
WITH data AS(
   SELECT COUNT (*) as a, E.b as b
   FROM         table1 C
   JOIN         table2 D
   ON           D.MY_ID = C.MY_ID
   JOIN         table3 E
   ON           E.NEW_ID = C.NEW_ID
   WHERE        E.b BETWEEN 1 AND 4
   GROUP BY     E.b
   ORDER BY     E.b
UNION ALL 
       SELECT COUNT(* )as a, E.b as b
       FROM          table2 D
       JOIN          table4 S
       ON            S.PERSON_ID IN (D.f_ID, D.g_ID)
       JOIN          table3 E
       ON            E.LOCATION_ID IN (Q.LOC_FROM_ID, Q.LOC_TO_ID)
       WHERE         L.AISLE BETWEEN 1 AND 8
       GROUP BY      E.b
       ORDER BY      E.b
)
SELECT sum(A) total, b 
FROM data
GROUP BY b;
```